# Can I call a activity class from a switch case?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a code in which it opens five fragment class,but i have one case to call activity class in my project.

Can I change case 3 to call activity class instead of fragment class?

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? Have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: I am unable to write logic of this code.

Comment: I want that when case 3 is called it should call Activity Class

Answer (score 2):

If your questions is whether you can call `new MyActivity()`, the answer is no.  Only the Android framework can instantiate an `Activity` and it does this based on an `Intent` being used in a call to `Context.startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by calling is starting the new activity, then small answer is YES, you can do that.

But if you mean to instantiate is then; No, you can't do that.

```
switch (position) {
case 0:
    *******WRONG WAY*******
    myAct = new MyActivity(); // Where MyActivity is extended from Activity
    break;
case 1:
    *******RIGHT WAY*******
    Intent intent=new Intent(MyCurrentActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
}
```